# Question about Shading

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders, texture-coordinates

I'm new to this website and i am new to Blender 3d so i have a question about shading.

Right now i am making an object and i am trying to tune in with the shading by adding some Texture and etc right now im adding "BUMP" at the shader and when im trying to tune in by changing the Strength of the Bump but nothing changes on my object

What is texture coordinate? It didn't change anything at all but i see some people they put that thing and it change the appearance.

I'm actually following a tutorial on Youtube and I'm making a donut as the object trying changing the shader but nothing change on the object which is weird. Some of the shader did work and some did not change anything to my object.

[image: Settings of the Shader]

Comment: Hello, Texture Coordinate allows you to choose how the texture will be projected on the object, will it be according to its proportion, UVs, etc... By default, if you don't plug the Texture Coordinate into the Noise Texture, it will be projected as Generated (the proportion of your object is used). Your setup should work as it is, but maybe share your file so that we can take a look: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: i added my blender file already plz take a look on my Shading thanks you

Comment: I may be blind... where is the link to the blend file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k1oPDPFvu0vVpzcxZKoELikCkT_N6wdU/view?usp=sharing

there i added gdrive link  idk why using that link that you give its not workin instead it give me a photo of my result lel idk the Texture Coordinator Didnt change anything even tho i connect the line to the Vector point

Comment: @VincentThamrin It's not enough to upload the file at the link which moonboots gave you, after uploading your file has a uniquely created link which you have to copy and paste here e.g. by editing your question and adding the link there.

Comment: @VincentThamrin Did you look at it only in _Material Preview_? The bump is visible there, but it's better in _Rendered View_. I'm not sure what you want to achieve. The bump is there and it changes when I change settings. Could you show screenshots of what you see and/or what you want/expect to see?

Comment: NVM i just found out the bumb is duplicate that's all and the Texture coordinator has been explain on other forum Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you have accidentally copied the node, so it doesn't connected

[image]

Comment: yeah i just saw idk why i Put double of the bump tho after deleting it and it starting to work but i still got another question why does Texture Coordinate doesnt apply any changes to my donut Tho im still wandering that question like didnt give a single changes

Comment: Double check all your nodes

Comment: i connect the Texture coordinate to "Vector"  in Noise Texture .